# Como registrar un usuario en Wordpress y otra aplicación simultáneamente?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin

Necesito orientación sobre el tema, he buscado algo de información pero no he encontrado lo que busco.
Lo que necesito es poder registrarme en una aplicación **PHP** con el mismo usuario y contraseña que lo hago en **Wordpress**.

Supongamos que un usuario se registra en mi blog de Wordpress con un usuario y contraseña, necesito que una vez registrado en mi blog con sus datos se registre en otra aplicacion externa con los mismos datos.

Espero me puedan ayudar con esto. Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Haz un web service securizado que te auto registre y llamalo desde wp

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya me has brindado un camino a seguir, podrías indicarme alguna referencia o guía para comenzar a desarrollar tu solución ?

Comment: Para el Web service la documentacion oficial -> http://php.net/manual/es/refs.webservice.php

Answer (score 1):

Si es otro script con PHP es simple, solo tendrías que requerir una vez el "wp-load.php" y ya con esto podrías usar el core de WordPress junto con su base de datos.

Ejemplo simple de login:

```
<?php

define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require_once('../../../../wp-load.php');

$redirect = ( is_ssl() ? 'https://' : 'http://' ) . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$args = array(
   'echo'           => true,
   'remember'       => true,
   'redirect'       => $redirect,
   'form_id'        => 'loginform',
   'id_username'    => 'user_login',
   'id_password'    => 'user_pass',
   'id_remember'    => 'rememberme',
   'id_submit'      => 'wp-submit',
   'label_username' => __( 'Username or Email Address' ),
   'label_password' => __( 'Password' ),
   'label_remember' => __( 'Remember Me' ),
   'label_log_in'   => __( 'Log In' ),
   'value_username' => '',
   'value_remember' => false
);

if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ){

    wp_login_form( $args );

    echo "You Must Be Logged In to Access This";

} else {

    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();

   printf(
      '<p>Welcome, %s!</p>',
      $current_user->display_name
   );

   printf(
      '<a href="%s">Logout</a>',
      wp_logout_url($redirect)
   );

}
```

**Antes de iniciar sesión:**

[image: Antes de iniciar sesión]

**Después de iniciar sesión:**

[image: Después de iniciar sesión]

Comment: Gracias, creo me puede ayudar con lo que necesito, lo probaré mas tarde y te dejaré saber si es la solución que buscaba. Solo tengo una duda y es el comportamiento de la variable $redirect.