# ¿Cómo redirecciono a la misma pagina en Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, login, script, cms, snippets

estoy rediseñando una pagina para una empresa y se ha creado un [evento](http://nuevositio.acrip.co/evento/encuesta-de-millennials-colombia-2020-las-generaciones-resilientes-son-la-clave-para-crear-una-mejor-normalidad/) donde el usuario tiene que hacer log in. Donde dice: **Inscríbite como afiliado haciendo login con tu usuario y contraseña aquí**

Pero el link que muestra el enlace esta oculto con un fragmento de código en WorPress  con el siguiente script que hacer el login:

```
add_shortcode( 'inscripcion', 'bp_contenido_inscripcion' );

function bp_contenido_inscripcion( $atts, $content = null ) {
   if ( is_user_logged_in() && !is_null( $content ) && !is_feed() )
   return $content;
   return '<p class="cuadro-inscripcion">Inscríbite como afiliado haciendo login con tu usuario y contraseña <a class="link-inscripcion" href="'.wp_login_url().'">aquí</a> </p>';}
```

¿Hay alguna forma de que se pueda hacer el login pero que mantenga en la misma página?

Comment: tal vez te convenga mostrar ahí mismo el form de login con [`wp_login_form()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_login_form/), ajustando los parámetros/args podes lograr que vuelva a la misma url desde donde se hizo login

Comment: Muchas Gracias por tu comentario. La verdad es que no soy muy bueno en JS (ya que soy FrontEnd) ... no se si me puedas ayudar con la implementación del código (y así hacer pruebas). Te estaría muy agradecido

Comment: es un form html ( impreso con una función php ), hay un ejemplo con "redirect a la misma pagina" aquí -> https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/178969/81450 hace el post al backend y luego se dirige a la url del parametro 'redirect', en esa respuesta tenes una forma de saber la url actual para pasarselo

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Veo que lo que me mandas esta en php, pero lo necesito en js para poder ponérselo al snippet que esta en el WP. Ya que este snippet abarcaría a todas las páginas donde se ponga para hacer login. GRACIAS de nuevo

Comment: si lo que buscas es un login con ajax fijate https://stackoverflow.com/a/59467436/1423096 y algo mas explicado en http://natko.com/wordpress-ajax-login-without-a-plugin-the-right-way/